# compose.ui.test in multi module app problem with launching activity

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I have a MainActivity in main app module, and then I have some feature modules. These feature modules has their own compose screens.

Using `createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()` I can create a rule that launches mentioned activity but this way I can only have UI tests in main module, because feature modules doesn't know about MainActivity what so ever. Is there a way to have compose UI tests in their corresponding modules?

I am also using kaspresso, but I think this part is irrelevant.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
abstract class BaseUiTest : TestCase(
    kaspressoBuilder = Kaspresso.Builder.withComposeSupport(
        customize = {
            flakySafetyParams = FlakySafetyParams.custom(timeoutMs = 5000, intervalMs = 1000)
        },
        lateComposeCustomize = { composeBuilder ->
            composeBuilder.semanticsBehaviorInterceptors = composeBuilder.semanticsBehaviorInterceptors.filter {
                it !is SystemDialogSafetySemanticsBehaviorInterceptor
            }.toMutableList()
        }
    )
) {
    
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>() // this is the problem
}
```

I am new to testing overall, and even newer to testing UI written in compose, so sorry for this vague question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createComposeRule()` instead of `createAndroidComposeRule()`

```
@get:Rule
val composeRule = createComposeRule()
```

then in test function:

```
@Test
fun myPerfectTest() = run {
        composeRule.setContent {
                MyParentScreen()
        }
        //your test code like step("click first button") {***}
}
```

`MyParentScreen()` is compose function contains your code to be tested.